Is the correspondence $F: x \in X \mapsto \{x' \in X : x' \preceq x\} \subset X$ continuous?
Let $X$ be a Euclidean space and $\preceq$ be a complete continuous preorder on $X$ (by continuous, I mean that it satisfies the following property: if $(x_n), (x'_n)$ are sequences in $X$ that converge to some $x,x' \in X$ respectively, and such that for every $n$, $x_n \preceq x'_n$, then $x \preceq x'$).
I wonder if the following correspondence is continuous (i.e. both upper hemicontinuous and lower hemicontinuous):
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
F:&X&\twoheadrightarrow&X\\
&x&\mapsto&\{x' \in X : x' \preceq x\}
\end{array}
\right..$$
I think that I proved that it is upper hemicontinuous: it follows from continuity assumption on $\preceq$ that the graph of $F$ is closed.
Now, I'm stuck for the lower hemicontinuous part...
Could you help me to show that it is (or not) lower hemicontinuous ? And if it's not, could you give me a sufficient condition on $\preceq$ ?
